# Can i use Distributed Database for a crawler?

Tags: mysql, database, distributed

can i use a distributed DB for my WebCrawler,what all are the available Open Source Distributed Databases?? can i use MySQL as my distributed DB? how amount of data can be stored?

Comment: There are some pretty good candidates for open-source distributed database here: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=open+source+distributed+databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDb might be right for you. It allows sharding and replication.

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier in a comment: use [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#distributed) (for instance).